Steady flow in galvanic cell - is there any convection in half-cells, or any salt bridge ions displacement?
Steady flow hypothesis in a galvanic cell consists in assuming that the ionic liquid in the cathodic half-cell (say, the ionic liquid $(Cu^{2+}, SO_4 ^{-2})$ in the $Cu^{2+}$ / $Cu$ half-cell), the ions in the salt bridge and the ionic liquid in the anodic half-cell (say, $(Zn^{2+},SO_4^{2-})$ in the $Zn^{2+} / Zn$ half cell) are not moving.
But there is in fact a concentration gradient that will occur between the zone close to the metal cathode (or anode) and the zone in the becker far away from the cathode (or anode); concentration gradient will provoke convection. Even more, there is displacement in the salt bridge, the positive ions will flow into the cathodic half-cell and negative ions of the salt bridge will flow into the anodic half-cell.
Are these displacements so slow that we can neglect them ? Perhaps the fact that the salt-bridge is a gelly slows down the velocity of its ions ?
Also shouldn't we use the term "stationary state", instead of "steady flow" ? Steady flow from what I've understood means that there is flow, but that this flow doesn't change with time.
